# VS 2013 build issue - exited with code -1073741819

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am struck with very strange issue..

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 (trial version). 
I am not able to build project successfully and always get the following **error**

```
'exited with code -1073741819'

Error   1   The command ""C:\HBS\repositry\HBS\HBS.TestSuite\.nuget\NuGet.exe" 
install "C:\HBS\repositry\HBS\HBS.Common\packages.config" -source ""  
-NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir 
"C:\HBS\repositry\HBS\HBS.TestSuite\ "" exited with code -1073741819.
HBS.Common
```

What im missing here?

Comment: -1073741819 is 0xc0000005 in hex.  A very well-known error code, Nuget is bombing with an AccessViolationException.  A *very* nasty sick machine syndrome, you can't get help for it here.

Comment: what's wrong with my machine?

Comment: Re-installing window will resolve this this issue?